# rEFind not working for Ubuntu OS X dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, refind

So, I partitioned my drive (macbook pro) installed ubuntu and rEFind and everything was working smoothly. I then updated to el capitan and now i can't access ubunutu because rEFind doesn't work.

I have tried to reinstall rEFind  and I get this message.

```
Do you want to attempt installation (Y/N)? y
Found suspected Linux partition(s); installing ext4fs driver.
Installing driver for ext4 (ext4_x64.efi)
Copied rEFInd binary files
Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.
Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc
ALERT:
Installation has completed, but problems were detected. Review the output for
error messages and take corrective measures as necessary. You may need to
re-run this script or install manually before rEFInd will work.
Unmounting install dir
Volume EFI on disk0s1 unmounted
```

I need some help, I'm a little over my head.

Cheers

Comment: I have now booted in recovery mode opened terminal and used the csrutil disable command. Now I have both dual boots and the rEFind working but I can only boot the os x from the recovery disk. Everything seems to be working fine, it's just a little strange. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial problem is caused by El Capitan's new SIP/CSR feature, and is covered in the rEFInd documentation:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html

The issue you describe in your comment of OS X booting from the Recovery HD partition is simply a matter of how Apple has chosen to name and use its partitions. Originally, Intel-based Macs placed their boot loaders on the OS X system (root, `/`) partition. With disk encryption and LVM setups, though, Apple had to move the boot loader elsewhere. The logical place to put it was on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) but for reasons known (only?) to Apple, they chose instead to put the boot loader on the Recovery HD partition, which already existed as tool for (as you might guess) recovering a damaged installation. rEFInd reports the name of the partition on which a boot loader is stored whenever possible. Thus, what you're seeing is Apple's decision, not a rEFInd bug *per se*.